# Cannot Firebase downloaded Url?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, angularfire

I have a Service TypeScript File with following Code

```
export class FirebaseService {
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private storage: AngularFireStorage) {}

  uploadFile(file: any) {
    const filePath = 'path/to/save/file';
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
    return task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        return fileRef.getDownloadURL()
      })
    ).toPromise();
  }

  createDocument(collection: string, name: string, file: any) {
    this.uploadFile(file).then(downloadURL => {
      if (downloadURL) {
        const data = {
          title: name,
          downloadURL: downloadURL
        };
        this.afs.collection(collection).add(data);
      } else {
        console.log("downloadURL is not defined.");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In my Component I have following code

```
export class CreatePage implements OnInit {
  name = ""

  file: any;

  onFileChanged(event: any) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
  }
  onSubmit() {
    console.log("this.selectedOption = ",JSON.stringify(this.selectedOption))
console.log("this.name = ",JSON.stringify(this.name,))
console.log("this.file = ",JSON.stringify(this.file))
console.log("TEST", this.file)

    this.firebaseService.createDocument(this.selectedOption, this.name, this.file)

    this.name = "", this.selectedOption = ""
  }
}
```

The output of the 4 values from console log is:

```
Selected option: freunde
this.selectedOption =  "freunde"
this.name =  "test"
this.file =  {}
TEST File {name: 'berge.jpg', lastModified: 1673618629595, lastModifiedDate: Fri Jan 13 2023 15:03:49 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 990092, …}
Selected option:
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ion-item>   <input type="file"  (change)="onFileChanged($event)"> </ion-item>
```

How can I fix this problem? The error message says following:

> core.mjs:9095 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field downloadURL.metadata.cacheControl in document freunde/lcAwFcHvQSo5iV6ExQPi)

It will upload the image to the storage, but not the downloaded url in the firebase firestore. Can someone help me please?

The Object look like this after printing the data object

```
data =  {
  "title": "test",
  "downloadURL": {
    "source": {
      "source": {
        "source": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and edit your question to use code blocks instead of putting each individual line in separate backticks. It'll be *much* more readable after that. Using triple backticks before and after the whole code block (with optional language indicator) is probably the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

#### Debugging step 1.

Make your code show exactly what you are sending to Firebase. Change the console.log to three console.logs

```
console.log("this.selectedOption = ",JSON.stringify(this.selectedOption,null,2))
console.log("this.name = ",JSON.stringify(this.name,null,2))
console.log("this.file = ",JSON.stringify(this.file,null,2))
```

#### Also add this before your call to `add`:

Before this:

```
this.afs.collection(collection).add(data);
```

Add this:

```
console.log("data = ", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
```

#### Show in your question the exact output from the above

This will maximise our chances of finding the problem.

#### Why `JSON.stringify`?

I can see by your comment that you are annoyed by my suggestion to use `JSON.stringify`. The reason to use it is to force the console.log output to be the instantaneous value of the variable at that time, rather than an automatically-updating value that might display a different value on the console than the value being experienced by your program at the time of the error.

#### You can now see the utility of the JSON.stringify!

Your simple console.log(this.file) is reporting the full value with properties filled in.

But the JSON stringify, is showing you that, at the time that the line was run, `this.file` was simply {}, i.e. an empty object. Firebase was being sent {}, not the filled-in object.

#### You can *also* see the value of the `,null,2`

This *would have* prevented the truncation of a line at:

```
size: 990092, ...
```

Volunteers on Stack Overflow would therefore have been able to tell if there was something later on in the object that was `undefined` or in some other way conflicting with Firebase.

These debugging tips are there to help us help you. If you don't follow the advice we give, it lessens people's enthusiasm to help.

Comment: I can get all those 3 values. I get the file value without the JSON.stringify

Comment: selectedOption: string = "";

Comment: We know you can get all those 3 values. Please show in your question the exact output from the above, for all three. The value with JSON.stringify is not necessarily the same as the output from a plain console.log, which is why we recommend it for debugging. JSON.stringify forces the output to be of the value at that moement in time, whereas the normal console.log can change its value (if it is an object) later.

Comment: I updated my answear and posted the output of the 4 values. can you do something with it?

Comment: Can you give me the whole code?

Comment: I updated my question. The Object is empty.. i don´t know why

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed my problem with following code.

I changed the uploadFile Function to following:

```
uploadFile(file: any) {
    const filePath = 'images/file';
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
    return task.snapshotChanges().toPromise().then(() => {
        return fileRef.getDownloadURL().toPromise()
    });
  }
```

Instead of returning a object I return now a Promise. This way we are waiting for the promise to resolve and getting the downloadURL. It should resolve the issue and allow the createDocument method to access the download URL without any error.